# What's the difference between a "range" and a "view" in the rangesv3 ts?

Tags: c++, range-v3

What's the difference between a "range" and a "view" in the rangesv3 ts?

Don't find any similar answers on G search. Guess I'm struggling with a basic overview of what each one is supposed to do:

is it the case (in c++ speak) that range 'is-a' view, or vice-versa?

Is it simply that a view is read-only range? Or perhaps that the "elements" in the range (what you get when you dereference the iterator) are const in one and not in the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean `view` and `action`?  A `view` is a range, it's just reads only.

Comment: Range V3 has [documentation that explains this pretty well](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views)

Comment: No, I do mean Range: reference: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs, [a range is](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#tutorial-quick-start):

> A range can be loosely thought of a pair of iterators, although they need not be implemented that way.

and:

> A view is a lightweight wrapper that presents a view of an underlying sequence of elements in some custom way without mutating or copying it. Views are cheap to create and copy, and have non-owning reference semantics.

A view *is* a range, just with more restrictions.

More formalized definitions in the TS are in the [Range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) and [View](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) concepts. Basically, a range is something that's iterable over, and a view is a range that is semiregular<sup>†</sup> and has constant time copy/move/assignment/begin/end/...

For instance, `std::vector<char>`, `std::string`, and `std::string_view` are all ranges, but only the last one is also a view.

---

<sup>†</sup> While in the Ranges TS, a View was always semiregular, this restriction was relaxed in [P1456](https://wg21.link/p1456). In C++20, a View is instead required to be only <s>default constructible and</s><sup>‡</sup> movable. The additional semantic constraints (all<sup>‡</sup> the operations being constant time) still hold. Notably: while a View need not be copyable, if it is copyable, then those copying operations still need to take constant time.

<sup>‡</sup>The default construction restriction was lifted in [P2325](https://wg21.link/p2325) and other requirements were further relaxed in [P2415](https://wg21.link/p2415).

Comment: "a view is a range that is semiregular and has constant time copy/move/assignment." and `begin`/`end`. *All* of the required operations for `View` are required to be O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the ref to the eric niebler's work. This is just like howard hinnant's chrono, where the best exposition of the material now in standard C++ is the original author's documentation.